# How do I keep a pop up always centered?

Tags: html, css

This isn't irrelevant: Roseannebarr.tumblr.com is where the theme I am making is.

How do I keep those popups centered if they are position:absolute;?

*Just so you know, I'm building a TUMBLR theme. Not a website.*

HTML: You can't see these tags if you view the source because they are the content.

CSS

```
body {
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; color:#3a3a3a;
font-size:12px;
background: #e4e4e2;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

#holder {
position: relative;  
width: 500px;  
margin:0 auto;  
}

#tooltip {
display: none;
position:absolute;
width:480px;
background:#6cb4e2;
padding:10px;
}

#outer:hover #tooltip {
display: block;
}

#outer {
float:left;
}

ul, ol {
margin: 5px 0 0 30px;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}

p {
margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

HTML

```
 <body>
<div id="holder">
{block:Posts}
<div id="outer">
{block:Photo}
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/zIrle9bek/block.png">
<div id="tooltip">

{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />{LinkCloseTag}
{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}

</div>
{/block:Photo}
</div>

<div id="outer">
{block:Text}
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/zIrle9bek/block.png">
<div id="tooltip">

{block:Title}
<h1>{Title}</h1>{/block:Title}
{Body} {block:More}<p><a href="{Permalink}">Read on...</a></p>{/block:More}

</div>
{/block:Text}
</div>

{/block:Posts}

<div id="outer">
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/zIrle9bek/block.png">
<div id="tooltip">

<h1>{Title}</h1>
{Description}

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI the site seems to hardly work with Chrome, unless it works far differently than I would expect.

Comment: If your getting the "Servers are over capacity" message, thats Tumblr. I'm using Chrome. Tumblr doesn't have a good habit of keeping their stuff up.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the size of your popups, set the CSS like this:

```
.popup {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  width:320px; height:240px;
  margin-top:-120px; margin-left:-160px;
}
```

This puts the upper left corner popup in the center of the page, and then the negative margins center it exactly.

Comment: @EarlLarson That is not enough information for me to help you further. I suggest you create a pared-down test case at something like http://jsfiddle.net/ showing your problem.

Comment: Tumblr uses it's own "Blocks". jsfiddle.net won't know what to do with them. Go to roseannebarr.tumblr.com and all I want is for each popup to be in the center of the screen even though it is positioned absolutely.

Comment: I went to your website in Safari and I saw nothing that made any sense to me. Make a pared-down test case.

Comment: Updated my OP. Can't make a pared-down test case because of the content "Blocks".

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an event handler to the resize event of the window. As the window is resized, your event handler will be notified to recalculate the new center and position the alert pop up accordingly.

Comment: Um thanks for the answer but I did it months ago and it was simple CSS. I just have a terrible memory :( If you look at the code, it has 0 javascript. It is all HTML and CSS made. The only reason I can't position it in the center is because it is absolutely positioned, and I MUST have it that way because if not each post moves the blocks.

Comment: Sounds like you need to plan your designs a little more before you start coding! ;)

Comment: I can't use javascript because that would create a popup where ALL blockas are stored. Each block need's its own div. All photo posts shouldn't be stored in one pop up, they need their own. That's why they were PLANNED this way.